# how to get a value from texbox c# to insert to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i tried to saved a value in DB, but  when  i make the insert, the DB don`t save any data from texbox when they texbox is load  from a javascript, this is my insert:

```
ConectarBD();   
Tabb = new SqlCommand("Insert  into peliculas  Values(@nombre_pelicula,@dias_arriendo,@valor_dia,@total_arriendo,@descuento,@total_pagar) ", Conn);
Dadap.InsertCommand = Tabb;
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@nombre_pelicula", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@dias_arriendo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@valor_dia", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@total_arriendo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@descuento", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@total_pagar", SqlDbType.VarChar);


Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@nombre_pelicula"].Value = txtNombrePelicula.Text;
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@dias_arriendo"].Value = txtNumDias.Text;
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@valor_dia"].Value = txtValorDia.Text;
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@total_arriendo"].Value = lblTotalArriendo.Text;
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@descuento"].Value =txtDescuento.Text;  
Dadap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@total_pagar"].Value = txtTotalPagar.Text;


Dadap.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblMensaje.Text = "Datos Grabados";
Conn.Close();
Limpiar();
txtRut.Focus();
```

Comment: How do you load the values from the database?

Comment: Your `insert into` looks incorrect, should be something like this `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)`

Comment: @VDWWD You do not have to list the columns for an insert if you are giving all the columns and in the correct order, but it is best practice.

Comment: @juharr, I never knew, you can learn something new every day ;)

Comment: You say "don't save any data ... when they texbox is load from a javascript". Please show the javascript that is being used and how it relates to your textboxes. Also include the whole `<form>` definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert looks wrong, try the following code and change column1,2,3... to columns names in your database.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Into peliculas (Column1, Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6) Values(@nombre_pelicula,@dias_arriendo,@valor_dia,@total_arriendo,@descuento,@total_pagar)";

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_pelicula", txtNombrePelicula.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dias_arriendo", txtNumDias.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor_dia", txtValorDia.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_arriendo", lblTotalArriendo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descuento", txtDescuento.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_pagar", txtTotalPagar.Text);

}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```